# Down Arrow Key not working. Need to reassign

Tags: keyboard

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu/etc, and I gabbed an old unused laptop from home. Turns out that the down arrow key doesn't work, an I need to reassign. I would like to reassign my PgDn key to be my down arrow key, but I have no idea where to start.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 Tahr

If you need any other info just ask and I will try to find it

Many Thanks